# current->mm gives NULL in linux kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I would like to walk the page table, so I have accessed the current->mm, but it gives NULL value.

I'm working on linux kernel 3.9 and I don't understand how could current->mm is zero.

Is there something I miss here?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/active_mm.txt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means you are in a kernel thread.

In Linux, kernel threads have no mm struct. A kernel thread borrows the mm from the previous user thread and records it in active_mm. So **you should use active_mm instead**.

---

**More details:**

in `/kernel/sched/core.c` you can find the following code:

```
static inline void
context_switch(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *prev,
           struct task_struct *next)
{
    ...
    if (!mm) {
        next->active_mm = oldmm;
        atomic_inc(&oldmm->mm_count);
        enter_lazy_tlb(oldmm, next);
    } else
        switch_mm(oldmm, mm, next);
    ...
}
```

If the next thread has no mm (a kernel thread), the scheduler would not switch mm and just reuse the mm of the previous thread.

Answer (score 1):

Need for active_mm assignment : The call to `switch_mm()`, which results in a TLB flush, is avoided by “borrowing” the `mm_struct` used by the previous task and placing it in task_`struct→active_mm`. This technique has made large improvements to context switches times.